# Pythonic way of collapsing/grouping a list to aggregating max/min

Tags: python, list, aggregate, list-comprehension

Lets say I have the following list in python.  It is ordered first by Equip, then by Date:

```
my_list = [
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Date': '2018-01-01'},
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Date': '2018-01-02'},
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Date': '2018-01-03'},
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2', 'Date': '2018-01-04'},
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2', 'Date': '2018-01-05'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Date': '2018-01-03'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3', 'Date': '2018-01-04'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3', 'Date': '2018-01-05'}
]
```

What I want to do is collapse the list by each set where a given piece of Equipment's job does not change, and grab the first and last date the equipment was there.  E.g., this simple example should change to:

```
list_by_job = [
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'First': '2018-01-01', 'Last': '2018-01-03'},
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2', 'First': '2018-01-04', 'Last': '2018-01-05'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'First': '2018-01-03', 'Last': '2018-01-03'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3', 'First': '2018-01-04', 'Last': '2018-01-05'}
]
```

A couple of things to note:

1. `A-2` on `Job 1` is only there for a single day, thus its `First` and `Last` Date should be the same.
2. A piece of equipment could be on a job, leave that job, and come back.  In this case, I'd need to see an entry for each time it was on the job, not just one single summary.
3. As stated before, the list is already sorted first by Equip, then by Date, so that ordering can be assumed.  (If there is a better way to sort to accomplish this, I am all ears)

For point 3, the list

```
my_list = [
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Date': '2018-01-01'},
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2', 'Date': '2018-01-02'},
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Date': '2018-01-03'}
]
```

should yield

```
    list_by_job = [
        {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'First': '2018-01-01', 'Last': '2018-01-01'},
        {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 2', 'First': '2018-01-02', 'Last': '2018-01-02'},
        {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'First': '2018-01-03', 'Last': '2018-01-03'}
    ]
```

Currently I am doing so in a simple loop/non-pythonic way:

```
list_by_job = []

last_entry = None
for entry in my_list:
    if last_entry is None or last_entry['Equip'] != entry['Equip'] or last_entry['Job'] != entry['Job']:
      list_by_job.append({'Equip': entry['Equip'], 'Job': entry['Job'], 'First': entry['Date'], 'Last': entry['Date']})
    else:
      list_by_job[-1]['Last'] = entry['Date']
    last_entry = entry
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this using Python's list comprehension, etc?

Comment: Looks more like a  job for pandas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
def _key(d):
  return (d['Equip'], d['Job'])

my_list = [{'Date': '2018-01-01', 'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1'}, {'Date': '2018-01-02', 'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1'}, {'Date': '2018-01-03', 'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1'}, {'Date': '2018-01-04', 'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2'}, {'Date': '2018-01-05', 'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2'}, {'Date': '2018-01-03', 'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 1'}, {'Date': '2018-01-04', 'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3'}, {'Date': '2018-01-05', 'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3'}]
new_data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(my_list, key=_key)]
final_result = [{"Equip":c, 'Job':d, 'First':b[0]['Date'], 'Last':b[-1]['Date']} for [c, d], b in new_data]
```

Output:

```
[{'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Last': '2018-01-03', 'First': '2018-01-01'}, 
 {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2', 'Last': '2018-01-05', 'First': '2018-01-04'}, 
 {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Last': '2018-01-03', 'First': '2018-01-03'}, 
 {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3', 'Last': '2018-01-05', 'First': '2018-01-04'}]
```

Edit:

Using data as suggested in your comment:

```
my_list = [{'Date': '2018-01-01', 'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1'}, {'Date': '2018-01-02', 'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2'}, {'Date': '2018-01-03', 'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1'}, {'Date': '2018-01-04', 'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2'}, {'Date': '2018-01-05', 'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2'}, {'Date': '2018-01-03', 'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 1'}, {'Date': '2018-01-04', 'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3'}, {'Date': '2018-01-05', 'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3'}]
```

Output:

```
[{'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Last': '2018-01-01', 'First': '2018-01-01'}, 
 {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2', 'Last': '2018-01-02', 'First': '2018-01-02'}, 
 {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Last': '2018-01-03', 'First': '2018-01-03'}, 
 {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2', 'Last': '2018-01-05', 'First': '2018-01-04'}, 
 {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Last': '2018-01-03', 'First': '2018-01-03'}, 
 {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3', 'Last': '2018-01-05', 'First': '2018-01-04'}]
```

Comment: I think `new_data` should be sorted by date too third (and not just `Equip` and `Job`). `itertools.groupby(sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (x['Equip'], x['Job'], x['Date'])), key=_key)`

Comment: `_key = itemgetter('Equip', 'Job')` would be the built-in way to create that key function.

Comment: Thanks!  It is almost there, but doesn't quite work for bullet-point 3 in my "couple of things to note".  For example, if you switch the second `A-1` Job to Job 2 (e.g.- the equipment went to job 1, then job 2, then back to job 1) there should be 2 entries for A-1 on Job 1 and 2 entries for Job 2, instead there is only one for each (that shows the absolute max/min on those jobs, instead of max/min per visit to job 1 and job 2.  I'll update my example above to show what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `pandas` for this.

`itertools.groupby` is cool but IMO a bit harder to comprehend.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> my_list = [
...:    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Date': '2018-01-01'},
...:    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Date': '2018-01-02'},
...:    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Date': '2018-01-03'},
...:    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2', 'Date': '2018-01-04'},
...:    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2', 'Date': '2018-01-05'},
...:    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'Date': '2018-01-03'},
...:    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3', 'Date': '2018-01-04'},
...:    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3', 'Date': '2018-01-05'}
...:]
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
>>> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
>>> groups = df.groupby(['Equip', 'Job']).agg({'Date': [min, max]}).reset_index()    
>>> groups.columns = ['Equip', 'Job', 'First', 'Last']
>>> groups
>>> 
  Equip    Job      First       Last
0   A-1  Job 1 2018-01-01 2018-01-03
1   A-1  Job 2 2018-01-04 2018-01-05
2   A-2  Job 1 2018-01-03 2018-01-03
3   A-2  Job 3 2018-01-04 2018-01-05
>>>
>>> groups.to_dict(orient='records')
>>> 
[{'Equip': 'A-1',
  'First': Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'),
  'Job': 'Job 1',
  'Last': Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00')},
 {'Equip': 'A-1',
  'First': Timestamp('2018-01-04 00:00:00'),
  'Job': 'Job 2',
  'Last': Timestamp('2018-01-05 00:00:00')},
 {'Equip': 'A-2',
  'First': Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00'),
  'Job': 'Job 1',
  'Last': Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00')},
 {'Equip': 'A-2',
  'First': Timestamp('2018-01-04 00:00:00'),
  'Job': 'Job 3',
  'Last': Timestamp('2018-01-05 00:00:00')}]
```

I suggest keeping the dates as time stamps.

Comment: I'd avoid pandas if you don't actually need it. It does not make sense to include  ahuge library to your project if you just need a simple function. Pandas make sense if you are dealing with big data sets and need performance. In all other cases it's just a huge dependency.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas here, which is some sort of "database interface" for data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
df2 = df.groupby(['Equip', 'Job']).agg(['min', 'max']).rename(columns={'min': 'First', 'max': 'Last'})
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel()
df2 = df2.reset_index()
result = df2.to_dict('records')
```

for the given sample input, this gives:

```
>>> df2.to_dict('records')
[{'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'First': '2018-01-01', 'Last': '2018-01-03'},
 {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Job': 'Job 2', 'First': '2018-01-04', 'Last': '2018-01-05'},
 {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 1', 'First': '2018-01-03', 'Last': '2018-01-03'},
 {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Job': 'Job 3', 'First': '2018-01-04', 'Last': '2018-01-05'}]
```

In case the date format is *not* `'%Y-%m-%d'`, then one first needs to convert it with `pd.to_datetime(..)` like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df2 = df.groupby(['Equip', 'Job']).agg(['min', 'max']).rename(columns={'min': 'First', 'max': 'Last'})
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel()
df2 = df2.reset_index()
result = df2.to_dict('records')
```

Comment: Thanks for the Pandas suggestion, and I agree, pandas is well suited to this.  However, this is being done in a web app/API and I've found in the past that loading pandas in django causes some issues with response time, etc.. and would prefer to keep things vanilla python.

Comment: @MarkD: well loading pandas the first time indeed takes some time, but after that, it can frequently take less time, since a DataFrame is *not* implemented in Python, but in C.

Comment: Are you just getting lucky by producing the correct output using strings or am I missing where you convert them to dates? I'm a bit confused. :)

Comment: @timgeb: if the strings are formatted `'%Y-%m-%d'`, then the lexicographical order is the same as the "date order". Since you can see a date as a three "digit" number (here digit is a bit a wrong word), where the digits have different radices. Only at the end of the "day" range, it increments the month range, and performs a wrap-around. So it works like a positional number system.

Comment: Ah, true. Probably still useful for future readers to mention that this works only for the exact format OP is using. I can't decide whether this is clever or dirty. Probably both. :)

Comment: @MarkD: if these are Django database records, you can actually already do this at the *database* level.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not.  In this case it is a legacy database that we need to sync with the new app's database.  (The list of raw/legacy data is used to generate new django ORM objects, but wasn't in the new format for date ranges, etc.. hence the need for this script/conversion).  Hopefully this code will only have to run for the next 6-8 weeks while we test the new app, and then the legacy server can be disconnected.